# How to render a Rails Partial with a Mousenter event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Bit of a jQuery/JavaScript beginner here so thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

I have an page `index.erb`, which contains:

```
 <div class="box">
   change me out
 </div>

 <div class="box">
   <p>change me out</p>
 </div>
```

and a partial `_more_info.erb`

```
<div class="update">
  <p>You've been changed</p>
</div>
```

What's the best way to render the partial when a user does a "mouseenter" event on any of the `class=box`?

Comment: hide the partial and show when mouseenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var boxHtml = $(".box").html();

$(".box")
    .mouseover(function() {
            $(".box").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'more_info')) %>");      
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
           $(".box").html(boxHtml);
    });
```

Comment: This works, but it updates all `<div class="box"></div>` elements when a mouseenter event triggers one of them. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You can use an id for the div where you want to render partial or use another attribute like rel in conjunction with class="box" for the divs you want to update with partial and modify identifier of mouseover event accordingly

Comment: var boxHtml = $(".box").html();

    $(".box")
        .mouseover(function() {
                $(this).html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'more_info')) %>");      
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
               $(this).html(boxHtml);
        });

Answer (score 0):

In your css:

`.update { display: none; }`

In the jQuery document ready function:

`$('.box').mouseenter(function() { $('.update').show(); });`

Comment: is it better to use mouseenter or mouseover? And do I need to call the partial (_more_info.erb) anywhere in the jQuery?

Comment: `mouseenter` doesn't bubble, `mouseover` does, so it depends on if you need the event to bubble. I honestly just put mouseenter because that's the one you mentioned in the question :)